# package org.springframework.beans.factory does not exist error

Tags: java, spring

I try to implement a simple hello world program using Spring framework. I have tried the following example in Windows environment without using IDE. In Eclipse IDE, it works fine.
In Windows command line prompt, I get following error messages.

```
C:\Users\Vijay\Documents\javaex\ex1>javac -d . Test.java  
Test.java:3: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory does not exist  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
                                        ^
Test.java:4: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml does not exist  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
                                            ^
Test.java:5: error: package org.springframework.core.io does not exist  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  

Test.java:6: error: package org.springframework.core.io does not exist  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  
                              ^
Test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol  
Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    ^
symbol:   class Resource  
location: class Test  
Test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol  
Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
                          ^
symbol:   class ClassPathResource  
location: class Test  
Test.java:11: error: cannot find symbol  
BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
    ^
symbol:   class BeanFactory  
location: class Test  
Test.java:11: error: cannot find symbol  
BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
                            ^
symbol:   class XmlBeanFactory    
location: class Test    

Please find the folder contents.

C:\Users\Vijay\Documents\javaex\ex1>dir  
26-04-2022  16:19               472 applicationContext.xml  
26-04-2022  19:22    <DIR>          com  
15-06-2012  17:30            61,464 com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar  
15-06-2012  17:30           547,837 org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar  
15-06-2012  17:30           355,598 org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar  
26-04-2022  17:16               250 Student.java  
26-04-2022  17:16               519 Test.java  
    
C:\Users\Vijay\Documents\javaex\ex1>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1\bin

C:\Users\Vijay\Documents\javaex\ex1>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Users\Vijay\Documents\javaex\ex1

Student.java 
package com.vijay;
public class Student {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public void displayInfo(){
        System.out.println("Hello: "+name);
    }
 }


Test.java
   package com.vijay;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
   import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
   import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
   public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
     BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
     Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");
     student.displayInfo();
   }
 }

Applicationcontext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="studentbean" class="com.vijay.Student">
<property name="name" value="Hello Vijay"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I have put Spring core jar files in same folder.
JAVA_HOME and CLASS PATH looks fine. I couldn't figure out why import is failing.
It would be great if someone helps to find out what could have been wrong?

Comment: Does your classpath include the necessary Spring jar files? I also strongly recommend using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle instead of compiling your source files manually by using `javac` directly, because managing Spring and all its dependencies manually is very cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree. I have done with Maven. It works. I used the same three Spring JAR files in Eclipse. It works.  I am trying to understand what went wrong in this case. As shown above, class path contains required Spring jar files. But it seems some issues in classpath so that JAR files are not imported. Not sure how to debug. This example is for educational purpose only.

Comment: Maybe sharing your (sensible snippet or entire) "hello world" would help? Good luck.